# How to construct an NFA in C++ that supports transitions that go back to an already visited state?

Tags: c++, nfa

I am trying to construct an [NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton) from a text file with the format:

```
state   1   start
state   2
state   3   accept
transition  1   0   2
transition  1   1   3
transition  2   0   1
transition  2   0   3
```

where state is:
state    [state #]    [start or accept]   [start or accept]
transition is: transition    [state transitioning from]    [symbol]    [state transitioning to]

I was able to get the program to work as long as there was no transition from one state back to that same state. (ex: adding in transition    1    0    1    to the file above does not work). I have been stuck on this for hours and I figured that I would have to try to implement a way to keep track of the configurations in order to get it to work to make sure that the same configuration is not tried more than once, but I cannot get it.
I was thinking of making a struct for Configurations and somehow implementing that into the evaluateInput() function, but I am stuck on how to go about it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string num, currentState, tranState;
char symbol;

struct Transition;

struct State{
    bool startS = false;
    bool acceptS = false;
    string sym;
    vector<Transition> transitions;//transition between states
};

struct Transition{
    string symb;
    State to;
    State from;
    bool eval = false;
};

struct NFA{
    vector<State> NFAStates;
    State start;
};

void evaluateInput(string in, NFA F)
{
    vector<State> currStates;
    vector<State> numAccept;

    for(int n = 0; n < F.NFAStates.size(); n++)
    {
        if(F.NFAStates[n].startS)
        {
            currStates.push_back(F.NFAStates[n]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++)
    {
        vector<State> next;
        for(int j = 0; j < currStates.size(); j++)
        {
            int tranSize = currStates[j].transitions.size();
            for(int k = 0; k < tranSize; k++)
            {
                if((currStates[j].transitions[k].eval == false) && (in.at(i) == currStates[j].transitions[k].symb))
                {
                    currStates[j].transitions[k].eval = true;
                    for(int m = 0; m < F.NFAStates.size(); m++)
                    {
                        if(F.NFAStates[m].sym == currStates[j].transitions[k].to.sym)
                        {
                            next.push_back(F.NFAStates[m]);
                            if(F.NFAStates[m].acceptS)
                            {
                                numAccept.push_back(F.NFAStates[m]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            currStates = next;
        }
    }

    if(numAccept.size() > 0)
    {
        cout << "Accept!" << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* fileName;
    string stringInput;
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        fileName = argv[1];
        stringInput = argv[2];
        //cout << stringInput << endl;
    }

    ifstream file(fileName);

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        NFA FA;
        string line;
        while(getline(file, line)){
            //cout << "1: " << line << endl;
            string ST;

            stringstream ss(line);
            getline(ss, ST, '\t');

            if(ST == "state")
            {
                State S;
                string SoA1;
                string SoA2;
                getline(ss, num, '\t');
                getline(ss, SoA1, '\t');
                getline(ss, SoA2);

                int num_i = stoi(num);
                S.sym = num_i;
                if((SoA1 == "start") || (SoA2 == "start"))
                {
                    S.startS = true;
                }

                if((SoA1 == "accept") || (SoA2 == "accept"))
                {
                    S.acceptS = true;
                }

                FA.NFAStates.push_back(S);
                if(S.startS == true){
                    FA.start = S;
                }
            }else if(ST == "transition")
            {
                Transition T;
                string symbol1;
                getline(ss, currentState, '\t');
                getline(ss, symbol, '\t');
                getline(ss, tranState);

                symbol = symbol1[0];
                int currentState_i = stoi(currentState);
                int tranState_i = stoi(tranState);
                T.symb = symbol;

                for(int j = 0; j < FA.NFAStates.size(); j++)
                {
                    if(FA.NFAStates[j].sym == tranState)
                    {
                        T.to = FA.NFAStates[j];
                    }
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < FA.NFAStates.size(); i++)
                {
                    if(FA.NFAStates[i].sym == currentState)
                    {
                        T.from = FA.NFAStates[i];
                        FA.NFAStates[i].transitions.push_back(T);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        evaluateInput(stringInput, FA);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you considered the [State Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make a whole lot of sense, as you have many (incomplete) copies of state objects that create by copy-ctor when your attempt to build your state machine representation.

Each `State` object contains a vector of `Transition` objects, and each `Transition` object in turn contains two `State` objects, `from` and `to`, which will be copies of the `State` objects made at the point where you happen to be parsing the transition line (so will contain the transitions already parsed, but not those yet to be parsed).

It would make a lot more sense if you change your `Transition` object to use `State *` or `State &` to refer directly to the `State` objects involved, rather than copying them.

Then too, when you try to evaluate the NFA, you again make copies of the states, which means that you cen easily get the same state multiple times in the vectors.  It would make more sense to use a `std::set<State *>` instead for these.  Similarly, in your `NFA` object, you would rather have a `std::map<std::string, State>` to make it easier to find states by name (and to avoid having all pointers be invalidated when you call `push_back` on a vector)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able follow your advice while using pointers instead of the copy constructor to have complete states instead of incomplete copies for the State objects in Transition. Also, I change my method of evaluating the NFA using a queue with an evaluation similar to breadth first search in order to figure this out.